# How to mark invoice as paid after partial payment

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I wrote a module that adds a 5% discount on the invoice, so that :

- if paid before X days, the paid amount is 95% of the invoice amount
- if paid later, the paid amount is 100% of the invoice amount

As it is now, the module works really fine, and you can see the code here: https://github.com/marclebrun/ml_cash_discount

I would like directions on how to modify the payment process, so that the invoice state is changed to **Paid** when the limit date is not reached yet and 95% are paid, **OR** when the limit date is reached and 100% are paid.

I have studied the code of the **account.payment** model, I tried to override the **action_validate_invoice_payment()** method, but with no success :

```py
    def action_validate_invoice_payment(self):
        for payment in self:
            for invoice in payment.invoice_ids:
                invoice.write({'state': 'paid'})
        
        return super().action_validate_invoice_payment()
```

Is there a code example that I have been missing and would you be so kind to point me in the right direction ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Where is your code or problem? Sounds like, you want to know how to use some panel. We solve coding problems here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Sorry, my code is here: https://github.com/marclebrun/ml_cash_discount - I didn't post the code in my question, because it works as expected, I just don't know how to do the next step with the payment... I will edit my question to explain that better, but thank you for your answer.

Comment: But where is the specific code, that handles your 5% formula and invoices? Do you have a specific programming problem or you are looking for a person to code for you? For that you can check out upwork.com

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain my problem clearly, I will try again :-)

Comment: So its getting more better as a question now. I also added python as tag. But the question is a bit vague still, maybe you can make it more specific. That would help it get a faster answer.

Comment: What version are you writing this for?

Comment: Odoo 12 community